# wordpress .htaccess www to nonwww (not working)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, lamp

I have a WordPress website. The permalink is changed so that a `.htaccess` file is created

I have one more requirement which is to redirect `www to nonwww`

for example I entered https://www.why-deny.com.hk/

it still didn't redirect to https://why-deny.com.hk/

After editing the `.htaccess`, www still unable direct to nonwww.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.why\-deny.com.hk [NC]
RewriteCond https://www.why-deny.com.hk/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://why-deny.com.hk/$1 [L,R=301]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

A record is added

httpd.conf virtual host are added

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.why-deny.com.hk
    Redirect permanent / https://why-deny.com.hk/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.why-deny.com.hk
    Redirect permanent / https://why-deny.com.hk/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Care to explain why this line is there? `RewriteCond https://www.why-deny.com.hk/ [NC]`

Comment: since i tried it doesn't work if only 1 rewritecond, thus i try to add the hardcoded condition to see if it works, anyway, it didnt work

Comment: nvm, even through RewriteCond https://www.why-deny.com.hk/ [NC] is removed, the www still unable redirect to nonwww

Comment: @SKLTFZ, try it in incognito window, browser caches redirects

Comment: one another thing you may forgot is to change siteurl in wordpress setting page

Comment: my siteURL is https://why-deny.com.hk.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.why\-deny.com.hk/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://why-deny.com.hk/$1 [L,R=301]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: still cannot redirect

Comment: yes, i masked my domain ... but the wordpress part was working, hmm

Comment: as the wordpress permalink must require the modified .htaccess to work

Comment: im using aws linux2 and only modified Directory to enable .htaccess (AllowOverride to ALL). site url is https://domain. i cant see other where which might affect rewrite rule of .htaccess

Comment: @SKLTFZ, did you setup correctly DNS records in Route 53?

Comment: can you access your domain with www at all?

Comment: i only hosted my server at AWS EC2, i didn't apply their dns service...

Comment: but i doubt if i really can access my site with www in my dns provider,  i will check and get back to you later :P

Comment: @SKLTFZ, if you are not using Route 53, then you need to add A record in your domain's registrar for your domain settings, that holds public IP of your EC2 instance. Then you need to edit and add virtual host for your domain in apache configuration in EC2 and restart service.

Comment: I have added the A record, added virtual host (plz see the updated content), the website can now access www.domain, but it is blocked due to privacy issue, actually i tried to disable it, but it doesn't work

Comment: it shows the NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error as the url redirected to https://www.domain after i entered http://www.domain

Comment: lol, i found the answer, HSTS force the redirection to HTTPS before it can start to do redirection of www > non www. then https://www.domainname violated the SSL cert as the cert only accept https://domainname. i also need to clear the cache so that HSTS will not affect the browser. the funny thing is, even though i removed virtual host of www.domain, & the redirection rule in the .htaccess. the redirection still works (www > non www), i have 0 handles explicit to redirect www > non www now but it still work..... it raise another issue of why it happens lol

Answer (score 0):

Please add this one before `# BEGIN WordPress`

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - why do you think that it solves the problem?